# Make page numbers jump by 2 libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, page-numbers

I'd like to have my page numbers on a document go 2, 4, 6, etc.. but I cannot figure out how I can do that on LibreOffice writer. I can only see an option to set an offset. Intuition suggests that I can to this in the "function" section of the field insert window but I've got no idea how to use that...
Can anyone please tell me how I can get only even numbers on the page number count in LibreOffice writer?

**Edit:** I found that I can put in formulae such as =3*2 to give me six, but I cannot figure out how I can put fields such as page number into such formula?

**Edit:** I need a way to do this without having page breaks between each page

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I have only even numbers on the page number count in LibreOffice Writer?

I don't believe this can be done automatically (although some LibreOffice Basic wizardry might be possible).

Here is a manual solution:

1. Edit the page footer and Insert Field > Page Number
2. In the *first* page of the document (which will be page 2):

   - Format (the first) Paragraph > TextFlow
   - Enable "With page style"
   - Set "Page number" to `2`

     [image]
3. Insert a page break.
4. In the *second* page of the document (which will be page 4):

   - Format (the first) Paragraph > TextFlow
   - Enable "With page style"
   - Set "Page number" to `4`
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for each page in the document adjusting the page number in step 4.
6. The page numbers in the footer will be 2, ,4, 6, ...

Example Print Preview:

[image]

Comment: Then... why not set each page number manually? What's the benefit of inserting all those page breaks with adjusted numbers?

Comment: @ngulam because how to you have a page footer that is different on every page? to the best of my knowledge (not much, I know) there is no way to do this... (if there was I'd be grateful to know it)

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Also see [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @DavidPostill No it didn't help enough, I need a way to do it without having page breaks since I have a continuous flow of text which I want to be able to modify without having to rearrange the page breaks every time I add or remove lines.

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon Then you should edit your question if you want to add additional restrictions to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the footer of the pages, then press F2 and a new toolbar will appear (Formula). Write this in the toolbar: =page*2 and click ok.

Haz click en el pie de las páginas, pulsa F2 y aparecerá una nueva barra de herramientas llamada fórmulas. Escribe allí =page*2 y haz click en el símbolo de OK.

Si no es eso exactamente lo que necesitas, puedes probar a hacer combinaciones. Un saludo.

Comment: First of, welcome to SuperUser! This is an english-only site, so you can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1355761/edit) your answer and remove the spanish.